# Can I close the Bootstrap modal once the link has been clicked?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Right now, I'm using this in a Bootstrap modal to redirect to a site:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" href="_blank">click</a>
```

I want the modal to be closed once the link has been clicked, so I thought adding `data-dismiss="modal"` to the tag would work, however it causes the modal to close without the link being opened.

Can I combine these and make the modal close *after* the URL opens?

Answer (score 18):

This works for me and doesn't require extra script tags:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="$('#myModal').modal('hide')">click</a>
```

Comment: this is not working in bootstrap version 5.0

Answer (score 4):

in boostrap 4 :

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" data-dismiss="modal" target="_blank">click</a>
```

Comment: Link doesn't work. It just closes the modal.

Answer (score 2):

Add one id to anchor tag. Then you can close the modal using that id once it get clicked.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" href="_blank" id="sample">click</a>

<script>        
    $("a#sample").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
`<a onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com/';" data-dismiss="modal">click</a>`

Answer (score 1):

something like the following should do it

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('modal-selector').modal('hide')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the already existing class in your element:

```
class="modal-close"
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in Bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code to whole project

```js
$(document).on('click', '.modal-hide-continue', function (e){
    $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

and it automatically works on any element with class name `modal-hide-continue` inside the modal.